# How do I add a field to a view that shows the user that published the node?

Tags: views, workflows, nodes

I am using Drupal 6.22 and the module Revisioning to create an approval process for the creation of new nodes. An "Author" user role can create the initial draft of the content and the "Moderator" user role must sign in to review and approve. Once a Moderator approves the content, they may publish it.

Revisioning does not allow an easy mechanism to display the particular user (of user role "Moderator") that published the content. According to this issue, the maintainer of the module will not build that feature: http://drupal.org/node/611586

I am attempting to create this feature myself. I have installed and configured the Workflow module, as referenced in the thread above. Each node now has a "Workflow" tab that shows the history of the Workflow states and it is possible there to see the username of the user that published the node (along with all other state changes, which my client does not care about). I have not been able to find a way to pull this information into a View field in order to display it in a View.

Is this possible?

I am happy to provide any additional information that may be useful in providing a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the `revisioning_content_summary` view which comes with the [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module. You'll find it at `admin/build/views/edit/revisioning_content_summary`.

It lists both the *User: Name* for the author and the *Node: Last edited by* for the moderator -- the information used in the *Revisions* tab, too.

Additionaly, have a look at creating views of type *Node revision*, which enable you to list all revisions of nodes, along with the revisioning information.

Comment: Thanks, Jan. I've been playing around with the revisioning_content_summary view and the workflow_history view that comes with the Workflow module. I am having a hard time pulling just a slice of the information they show. For instance, the workflow_history view shows the user that changed the state of every workflow state change (draft -> moderator -> public), but I can't figure out how to just show the change to the public state.